# Authentication in GeoServer with OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to authenticate in GeoServer with a external webpage (made with asp.net and OpenLayers)? I have restricted the access data only by certain users, and I don't want to authenticate this way:

```
username:password@geoserverurl
```

for security reasons (the username and password are visible in the webpage code)

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to have GeoServer behind your web server. This way your requests are received by web server (IIS) first where you authenticate user and then allow features based on roles.

While there are [GeoServer Authentication](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Enhancing+Geoserver+Authentication) options and [GeoPrisma](http://geoprisma.org/site/index.php), I think for 90% of apps could use this proxy approach and retain all Geo/Map data securely behind a firewall.

Cheers,
Ramesh